# Passing linked lists into structures

Tags: c, function, linked-list

Okay, so this might be my most loaded question yet, as I hate to post large amounts of code for a question, but I simply can't find a way to simplify it for the purpose of this question as I don't really understand linked lists enough to do so. Structures make sense to me, but linked lists really throw me off for some reason. Anyways, I need to make a modular program for doing various tasks as directed by the user. I started out by putting the program in main to keep it simple:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>      /* has the malloc prototype      */
#define TSIZE 50         /* size of array to hold title   */
struct film {
    char title[TSIZE], author[TSIZE],year[5];
    struct film * next;  /* points to next struct in list */
};
typedef struct film * Node;
int main(void)
{
    Node head = NULL;
    Node prev, current;
    char input[TSIZE];
    const char fname[]="HW15Data.txt";
/* Gather  and store information          */
    FILE * fp;
    char line[256];
    int loops=0;
    fp=fopen(fname,"r");
    while(current != NULL){
        current = (Node) malloc(sizeof(struct film));
        if (head == NULL)       /* first structure       */
            head = current;
        else                    /* subsequent structures */
            prev->next = current;
        current->next = NULL;
        if (fgets(current->title,sizeof(line),fp)==NULL) break;
        if (fgets(current->author,sizeof(line),fp)==NULL) break;
        if (fgets(current->year,sizeof(line),fp)==NULL) break;
        prev = current;
        loops++;
    }
/* Show list of books from file                    */
    if (head == NULL)
        printf("No data entered. ");
    else
        printf ("Here is the books list:\n");
    current = head;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        printf("Book: %sAuthor: %sYear: %s\n",
        current->title, current->author, current->year);
        current = current->next;
    }
    printf("Number of records wrote: %d\n",loops);



/* Program done, so free allocated memory */
    current = head;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        free(current);
        current = current->next;
    }
    printf("Bye!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

So, somehow, this works the way it is supposed to. Now, I try to make it modular, and from the first function IntializeList I ran into problems. So, for the purpose of making this match up better with my first program, I wrote the rest of what I wanted to do, ignoring the function passing issues. Obviously, the compiler now has thrown a fit of errors at me, and I can't really figure out what to do from here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>      /* has the malloc prototype      */
#define TSIZE 50         /* size of array to hold title   */
struct book {
    char title[TSIZE], author[TSIZE],year[5];
    struct book * next;  /* points to next struct in list */
};
//typedef struct book ITEM;
typedef struct book * Node;     // struct book *
void InitializeList(Node *List);
void InitializeList(Node *List){
    *List = NULL;
    puts("Initialization successful.");
}   
void Append(Node *List, char filename[TSIZE]);
void Append(Node *List, char filename[TSIZE]){
    FILE * fp;
    Node head=NULL;
    Node prev, current;
    char line[256];
    int loops=0;
    fp=fopen(filename,"r");
    while(current != NULL){
        current = (Node) malloc(sizeof(struct book));
        if (head == NULL)       /* first structure       */
            head = current;
        else                    /* subsequent structures */
            prev->next = current;
        current->next = NULL;
        if (fgets(current->title,sizeof(line),fp)==NULL) break;
        if (fgets(current->author,sizeof(line),fp)==NULL) break;
        if (fgets(current->year,sizeof(line),fp)==NULL) break;
        prev = current;
        loops++;
    printf("Number of records wrote: %d\n",loops);
    }
}
int Print(void);
int Print(void){
    int num;
    int i=0;
    if (head == NULL){
        printf("No data entered. ");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Enter record # to print: ");
    scanf("%d",num);
    current = head;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        for (i=0;i<num;i++){
            current = current->next;
        }
        printf("Book: %sAuthor: %sYear: %s\n",
        current->title, current->author, current->year);
    }
    return 0;
}
int WriteBinary(const char * pfname);
int WriteBinary(const char * pfname){
    FILE * fp;
    fp = fopen(pfname,"wb");
    if (head == NULL){
        printf("No data to write. ");
        return -1;
    }
    current = head;
    while (current != NULL){
        fwrite(current->title,sizeof(TSIZE),1,fp);
        fwrite(current->author,sizeof(TSIZE),1,fp);
        fwrite(current->year,sizeof(TSIZE),1,fp);
        current = current->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
int main(void){
    Node head;
    Node prev, current;
    int books;
    InitializeList(&head);
    char input[TSIZE];
    char fname[]="HW15Data.txt";
    char op;
    do{
        puts("Select operation from the following list:");
        puts("i. Initialize    a. Append    p. Print");
        puts("w. Write binary file    q. quit");
        op = getchar();
        while (getchar()!='\n');
        if (op=='i'){
            InitializeList(&books);
        }
        else if (op=='a'){
            /* Gather  and store information          */
            books=Append(&head,fname);
        }
        else if (op=='p'){
            /*Print book record of user's choice*/
            Print();
        }
        else if (op=='w'){
            /*Write list in binary to a file*/
            WriteBinary("HW15bin");
        }
        else if (op=='q'){
            /* User quit, so free allocated memory */
            current = head;
            while (current != NULL)
            {
                free(current);
                current = current->next;
            }
            printf("Bye!\n");
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            /* Program done, so free allocated memory */
            current = head;
            while (current != NULL)
            {
            free(current);
            current = current->next;
            }
            printf("Invalid characted entered. Bye!\n");
            return 0;
        }
    } while (op!='q');
    return 0;
}
```

All I really need to do I just clean up how things are passed or not passed to and out of functions and I should be all set! I'm sure this is an extremely loaded question and will likely be my last one for a while, but at this point I don't really know what to do. If anyone does answer this, you're a freaking legend.

Comment: `free(current); current = current->next;` : `current` can not be used after `free`.

Comment: You forgot use `List` in `Append`. Also `while(current != NULL){` using uninitialize variable at first time.

Comment: `void Append(Node *List, char filename[TSIZE]){` :: You never assign to `*List` in this function.